# SQL Server Determining Hard Coded Date as Larger When It's Not?

Tags: sql-server

An old employee left a massive query behind that I've been debugging and it appears that the issue has come down to SQL Server itself determining a comparison differently than what I would have expected.

I have a table with a column `col1` containing the value `20191215` as a datetime.

The part in question is similar to the following:

```
select case when col1 > '01/01/2020' then 1 else 0 end
```

This statement is returning `1`, suggesting that `'12/15/2019'` is larger than `'01/01/2020'`.

I do not need assistance correcting the query, as I have already made changes to do so other than using the comparison the previous employee was using, I am simply curious as to why SQL Server would evaluate this as I have described.

I understand that this is not the typically way SQL Server would store dates as well, would the issue simply be the formatting of the dates?

Current SQL Server version is: `SQL Server 2014 SP3 CU3`.

[SQL Fiddle link that shows the same results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/40971/1)

*Please note that the link does not contain an exact replica of my case*

Edit: Included additional info relevant to actual query.

Comment: Are you sure that `01/01/2020` is actually a string. And not doing this `select case when cast('20191216' as datetime) > 01/01/2020 then 1 else 0 end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a **string comparison** not a date comparison:

```
select case when '12/15/2019' > '01/01/2020' then 1 else 0 end
vs
select case when CAST('12/15/2019' AS DATE) > CAST('01/01/2020' AS DATE) then 1 else 0 end
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=80100ba064150ac9d0324eff49120d62)**

> I am simply curious as to why SQL Server would evaluate this as I have described.

`'12/15/2019'` it is a string literal, SQL Server does not know you want to treat a date unless you explicitly express your intention.

---

> I have a table with a column col1 containing the value 20191216

If you are comparing with a column then the data type of column matters and [data type precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Austin - please update your question so the example reflects your actual case then

Comment: @Austin The key point is data type of column. Please post the data type

Comment: @Austin I could not reproduce your case: **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=66b9f71c766f04a9cb06d570f048538c)**, string literal is automatically converted to datetime and it is returing 0 as intended

Comment: @Austin  I understand you could not share your codebase. I could recommend searching for conversion both implicit/explict - they are probably the reason of the observed behaviour. Good luck!